# How to reload a single jqGrid row after updating a column so as to run the custom Formatter

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with server side pagination.

I have a custom formatter on certain columns of the row which depending on the text of a hidden column highlights words in those columns.

After some operations the text in the hidden column changes and the highlighting should also change.But when I update the value of hidden column using **setRowData** the custom formatter is not triggered.

After searching for a while I found out that the formatter is only called while row creation and not while updating.

In the end I have to reload the entire grid to get the necessary changes, but this has performance issues.

Is there a way to refresh a row or trigger the colmodel properties after updating a row?
Can I delete and then add the row at the same place?

Just a hint is enough.I have been searching for the past 2 days but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you Stated before... the setRowData doesn't trigger the formatter methods in order to properly generate the cell contents. So one way to strike this problem is to update the columns individually. Using the provided functionally to archive this :

```
jQuery("#positions_grid_body").jqGrid('setCell', idRow,index,the_data_of_the_cell);
```

> where index can be string referring to the name of the column, or a number referring to the position of the column (starting at cero).

Hope it helps!.